# SvgDocument.Draw() Object reference not set to an instance of an Object

Tags: vb.net, svg

I have looked around Stackoverflow and the internet in generel, but haven't found a post that could help me solve my problem.

My problem is that in the following code snippet at line

```
Dim bm As Bitmap = SvgDoc.Draw()
```

I get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Protected Function SvgToPng(ByVal svg As String) As Byte()
    svg = svg.Replace("url(""#lineArea"")", "url('#lineArea')")

    Dim byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(svg)
    Dim str As New MemoryStream(byteArray)
    Dim svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open(str)
    scaleSvgDoc(svgDoc, 7)
    Dim bm As Bitmap = svgDoc.Draw()
    Dim out As New MemoryStream
    bm.Save(out, ImageFormat.Png)
    Return out.ToArray
End Function
```

I have multiple buttons, under different menus that access this method. My problem is that for a single of these menus, I get the problem as described above, but I don't get it for the rest.
I have checked that both the **SvgDoc**, **str** and **byteArray** all are set, and the only difference between the working one, and one that doesn't work, is the **SvgString** (in this case **svg**).

Anyone that can help me here?

EDIT: It's the SVG Rendering Engine library that I use.

Comment: Didn't post the SvgStrings, as they were to long for the post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this library, I assume you are using SVG Rendering Engine?  But I noticed that there is a method SvgDocument.OpenAsBitmap.  Why not just open as a bitmap and then change to whatever image format you want?

Comment: As far as I can see from the source code, it has been implemented as "return null".
According to https://svg.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/SvgDocument.cs.